# Run a particular java class in a URL as a JSP or independent class

Tags: java, class, jsp, servlets

I am a core java developer, I have created a class which receives audio from an android device and throws the received data to the pc speakers. The class is running in my local machine and the device is sending data to it using my machine's IP address. Now, I have to host the class to the server and make the class available to internet users. As I do not have knowledge about Java web technology so I do not know what to do to host the class.

The java class:

```
class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 8000;



    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);

        /**
         * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
         * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
         * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
         * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
         */

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[5000];

        format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

        while (status == true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    receivePacket.getData());

            ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
            toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());

        }



    }

    public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
        try {

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            sourceDataLine.open(format);

            FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            volumeControl.setValue(6.0206f);

            sourceDataLine.start();
            sourceDataLine.open(format);

            sourceDataLine.start();

            System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

            sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
            System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Please tell me what to do in order to host the class. Please excuse me if the question is a bit stupid.

Comment: you want to have a jsp page and you want to send request to server from that page to execute the methods in your class. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia I have no idea what to do, right now the class is running in my local machine, I want the class to be accessed through an URL, just as a webservice to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can do I prefer  webservice in particular REST

1)Expose it as a  service using EJB

2)Expose it as webservice REST or SOAP so it can be accessed by others over web

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC21/developing-a-jax-ws-pojo-web-service.html

http://wso2.com/library/3151/

Comment: It will be very helpful if you give me some suggestions on my code, I absolutely have no idea about EJB or any other Java Web technologies..............

Comment: Just refer to links how to expose a simple pojo calculator as webservice on web

Comment: U cannot have main method on web put your logic in method and expose as service. like www.example.com/CalculatorService/Add

Comment: Can you please just tell me how do I make the class without a main method

Comment: instead of your main method expose it as  some processAudio method like public void processAudio()

Comment: and where will I call the method?

Comment: Should I put the contents of main method in a static block of code?

Comment: peopel who use ur method will call your method